# remove additional braces after converting xml to json

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, xml-parsing, xml2js

I used the `xml2js` to convert the following xml string to `json`

```js
export async function parseXml(xmlString: string) {
  return await new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    parseString(xmlString, (err: any, jsonData: Book) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(`Unable to parse to xml due to: ${err}`);
      }
      console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
      resolve([jsonData]);
    })
  );
}
```

Below is the xml I am trying to convert

```xml
<books>
<book>
    <title>harry potter</title>
    <author>JK Rowling</author>
    <isbn>12fgrwgrgrgrtgrg</isbn>
    <quantity>10</quantity>
    <price>4.5</price>
</book>
<book>
    <title>goosbumps</title>
    <author>R.L Stein</author>
    <isbn>12fgrwg12334tgrg</isbn>
    <quantity>6</quantity>
    <price>2.5</price>
</book>
</books>
```

however once I pass the xml string through the function, I get the following output

```json
{
  "books": {
    "book": [
      {
        "title": [
          "harry potter"
        ],
        "author": [
          "JK Rowling"
        ],
        "isbn": [
          "12fgrwgrgrgrtgrg"
        ],
        "quantity": [
          "10"
        ],
        "price": [
          "4.5"
        ]
      },
      {
        "title": [
          "goosbumps"
        ],
        "author": [
          "R.L Stein"
        ],
        "isbn": [
          "12fgrwg12334tgrg"
        ],
        "quantity": [
          "6"
        ],
        "price": [
          "2.5"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

However I wanted something like the following

```json
  {
    book: {
      title: 'harry potter',
      author: 'JK Rowling',
      isbn: '12fgrwgrgrgrtgrg'
    },

    stock: {
      quantity: 10,
      price: 4.5
    }
  },

  {
    book: {
      title: 'goosbumps',
      author: 'R.L Stein',
      isbn: '12fgrwg12334tgrg'
    },
    stock: {
      quantity: 6,
      price: 2.5
    }
  }
];
```

Is there anyway to get it to the format I want without doing some complicated string replacement?

Answer (score 1):

Use `explicitArray: false` option

> Always put child nodes in an array if true; otherwise an array is created only if there is more than one.